# Kafka Offset commit failed on partition test3-0 at offset 29: This is not the correct coordinator

Tags: apache

When I tested Kafka, the error occurred. I did not understand what it meant,
There are three servers, I shut down the other two without any problem, but when I shut down the other one, this error will occur

```
[2018-08-30 08:51:48,824] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-08-30 08:51:49,044] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-08-30 08:51:49,151] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-08-30 08:52:14,004] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Offset commit failed on partition test3-0 at offset 29: This is not the correct coordinator. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-08-30 08:52:14,115] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Offset commit failed on partition test3-0 at offset 29: This is not the correct coordinator. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-08-30 08:52:14,224] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-51176] Offset commit failed on partition test3-0 at offset 29: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```